# Git plugin for Zend Studio 9 (eclipse) not Pushing upstream

Tags: eclipse, git, zend-studio, egit, jgit

When I try to push added and committed changes upstream I get a dialog box with a 'Message Detail field" that indicates:

```
Repository git@git.somehostedplace.com:somerepo.git

Not Implemented! TODO
```

On the command line I can push to the repo, so I'm pretty sure it's a Zend/Eclipse issue.  Anyone ever see this before and have any idea what's going on?

My versions of JGit and EGit is 1.3.0.20120215

Additionl information: When I browse on the command line to the project workspace and the code, I can push it and I get the same TODO message.  The issue seems limited soley to the IDE created copy, because if I do a regular git clone on the command line everything works fine...

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, but you should have a look at your eclipse error log and paste any relevant errors.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg unfortunately, it's not throwing any java errors in the Zend error log.

Comment: Perhaps a network/proxy problem?  Eclipse uses separate proxy settings  than the rest of your system.  Go to Preferences -> General -> Network settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after digging around a bit I found that if you right click on the Git project and select Team->Remote->'Configure Push To Upstream' a dialog opens.

A box at the bottom of the dialog labeled "Ref Mapping" with some odd stuff in it.  I deleted the entry in the box and now I can push without any issue.